# Remove \n from produced file

Tags: perl

The bit of code below is used in a script that queries a database and produces an output file of records.  One problem that I am having is that a newline character seems to be inserted at the very end of the file and it is causing grief with another script I am working on to import the data into another database.  I thought this would be as easy as a `chomp` on the filehandle but that is not allowed.  I have read many ways to do this on the net but not sure the path to take. Do you guys see a way to do this?

```
while ($queryResults->MoveNext() == $CQPerlExt::CQ_SUCCESS) {
        $swCR = $session->GetEntityByDbId("SWCR", $queryResults->GetColumnValue(1));

        # Gather data       
        $swID = $swCR->GetFieldValue("RecordID")->GetValue();
        $swData = "<RecordID>" . $swID . "</RecordID>";
            foreach $fieldName (@fieldNames)
                {
                $swData = $swData . "<" . $fieldName . ">" . $swCR->GetFieldStringValue($fieldName) . "</" . $fieldName . ">";
                            }

        # Build file with records seperated by custom line delimiter
        print OUTFILE $swData . "~~lineDelimiter~~\n";
                                }

close(OUTFILE);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're getting?

Comment: *"a newline character seems to be inserted at the very end of the file and it is causing grief with another script I am working on"* In that case your other program isn't very robust. You should change it to ignore blank lines

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you guys late....had to run to kids Halloween parade.  I completely agree that the script that uses the data should be able to handle the \n but I don't still see why I should allow my export script to make the mistake in the first place.  I have control over the export of data per the code below.

Comment: @Sobrique - my output data are rows of records which end with ~~lineDelimiter~~.

Comment: At the bottom of my file on a separate row is a \n.  I was hoping to easily chomp that out but perl mechanics are getting the best of me.

Comment: You can only chomp data inside of your program. If you `my $foo = chomp <$fh>` your data gets read first and chomped and then assigned. It's not chomping the file handle. [The other Matt explains it below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33439602/1331451) in a nice way.

Comment: Ok understood.  Makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output the newline at the beginning of each line instead of the end, and skip the first one.

```
my $count = 0;
my @stuff = qw(a b c d);
while (my $letter = shift @stuff) {
  print "\n" if $count++;
  print $letter;
}

print "__test";
```

This will output:

```
a
b
c
d__test
```

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying....why clean up the file if I can prevent the mistake in the beginning.  Ok let me play with this and try to implement in my script.  Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have complete control over the output, I would attack it from that angle by never emitting the final newline in the first place. However, since this is Perl we're talking about, there's more than one way to do it. ;-)

I'm using [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) here to truncate the file to 1 byte less than whatever it was before (`-s` returns the file size in bytes).

```
my $file = 'test.txt';

open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die $!;
print $fh "$_\n" for 1..10;
close($fh);

truncate($file, (-s $file) - 1);
```

Output:

```
$ od -c test.txt
0000000    1  \n   2  \n   3  \n   4  \n   5  \n   6  \n   7  \n   8  \n
0000020    9  \n   1   0
0000024
```

Comment: Right. I'm saying I wouldn't if given the choice. But if you're going to, here's how to deal with it.

Comment: Add an explanation for `truncate` and a link and this is a great answer. :)

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted. It's not the smartest solution, but it answers the question. Just because we have an xy problem that doesn't mean answers that address the immediate problem should be punished.

Comment: Beats me. Hit-and-run downvotes are annoying, but unless the downvoter speaks up, we'll never know what was wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Matt I'm not quite sure what down-voted really means yet because I am new to the site but if it means anything your a genius to me.  I can't thank you enough for taking the time to answer my question.  I tried what you suggested and read the perl doc and it's a great solution to my issue.  One thing was weird is that I need to truncate by 2.  I'm not quite sure if there was two newline indicators or it treated the \ and n separately as 2.  Also, not sure why we vote on each others questions and answers.  I could have a PHD in programming, or a dropped out in 3rd grade.

Comment: @Simbabque - again I really appreciate the time you spent looking at my code and answering my question.  Thanks to everyone that weighed in and offered knowledge.  I'm learning and more importantly having fun.

Comment: Having fun is important. Voting is not really for the one asking the question. It's for the people that come later. SO is a knowledge base. Answers with high vote count were considered useful by the community. A downvote means that user thought the post wasn't useful or constructive. You should read the [faq] to learn more about that. Who someone is or what level of education they have doesn't matter here. We're all writing code, that's what counts. :-)

Comment: OK makes sense to me.  Just wanted to make sure I thanked everyone for taking time out of their day to answer a question from a total stranger.  This place is coooool!